# Custom Double Handle Slider

Tags: iphone, uislider

I was wondering if anyone had some code, or knew of a place that has code for creating a double handled slider.  (EX. Kayak application filter results time, has a slider with thumbs on both ends to create a range.) I am looking to do something similar using a double slider to search for a range of ages on a person array.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a double slider and posted it on GitHub.

Blog post: http://dev.doukasd.com/2010/08/double-slider/

GitHub page: https://github.com/doukasd/iOS-Components/tree/master/Controls/DoubleSlider

Let me know how it works for you.

Comment: I ended up creating my own as well, but i tested yours out.

I can only drag for a few pixels then the thumb locks up and i have to retouch it and drag a few more pixels.

Comment: Yes that's because the drag handlers are too small. If you resize them you don't get this issue. Of course the proper solution would be to latch the finger until you release it. I'll add that in the to-do list :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I wrote one and posted it to git hub, too. Wish I'd seen Dimitris' earlier!

http://github.com/cmezak/CMRangeSlider

Comment: I tried using yours sider but it dint work. I am not able to move it a bit.

Comment: I need to post a newer version to github. Will try to do that soon if you follow it.

Answer (score 0):

I just found a really nice one. There is an article on how it was built and on the second page a link to the github repository. It looks like something Apple would have done!

[Wicked Double Slider](http://buildmobile.com/wicked-ios-range-slider-part-one/#fbid=ry1QSCnXs4t)

Posting this as I have a need for a really nice slider, found this page first, with so-so reviews of the projects, then later tripped on what appears to be a commercial quality project