# Double slide to unlock for iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, uislider

I want a control for iOS that slides left-to-right, similar to slide to unlock, but also slides right-to-left. I want something very similar to the control on Android's lock screen, where sliding left-to-right unlocks and sliding right-to-left silences.

[image]

1. It seems like this would be easiest to implement by subclassing `UISlider`, right? Would I need two sliders, or should I do it with just one?
2. Are there already any open source versions of this?

#### Ideas

Here's an idea of what the protocol might look like:

```
@interface DoubleSlider : UISlider

typedef enum {
    DoubleSliderDirectionLeftToRight,
    DoubleSliderDirectionRightToLeft
} DoubleSliderDirection;

@end

@protocol DoubleSliderDelegate <NSObject>

@optional

- (void)doubleSlider:(DoubleSlider *)doubleSlider
didBeginSlidingWithDirection:(DoubleSliderDirection)direction;
- (void)doubleSlider:(DoubleSlider *)doubleSlider
didEndSlidingWithDirection:(DoubleSliderDirection)direction;

@end
```

#### Related

- [iPhone "slide to unlock" animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/438046/iphone-slide-to-unlock-animation)
- [Slider which helps to unlock the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4236998/slider-which-helps-to-unlock-the-iphone)
- [UISlider, slide to unlock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816891/uislider-slide-to-unlock)
- [iPhone:Programming UISlider to position at clicked location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895122/iphoneprogramming-uislider-to-position-at-clicked-location)
- [Custom Double Handle Slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3283165/custom-double-handle-slider)

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any third party versions for this. I don't feel that UISlider would be a good place to begin. If I were you, I would subclass a UIScrollView instead.

Set it up at the bottom of the screen to have a height of 44 pixels or so. Lay down the images at the appropriate positions on the scrollView like in the image you posted.

Then, conform to the [UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html) and implement the [scrollViewDidScroll:](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006923-CH3-SW3) method to track when the user slides it left or right. Inside this method, check the [contentOffset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW6) property of the UIScrollView. By trial and error, you can find out the exact content offsets where you feel that sliding the scrollview should trigger the actions you're looking for.

For example, if the contentOffset being 50 means that it's for DoubleSliderDirectionLeftToRight, you can fire off the delegate callback and then have the scrollview 'jump back' to the original position by using [scrollRectToVisible:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006922-CH3-SW26)

Sorry for the long winded and RTFM-ish answer, but I have no code to support this. This is just speculation, but I don't see why this solution would not work :)